# Не создается наследник Application в jax-rs на wildfly 13

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, jax-rs

Пытаюсь запустить REST сервис на `jax-rs`.

```
@ApplicationPath("test")
public class App extends Application {
    public App() {
      super();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
      return Stream.of(MyServlet.class, AnotherServlet.class)
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Ни конструктор, ни `getClasses()` не вызываются (проверял дебаггером).
Как можно это решить? Использую `wildfly 13`, `resteasy`. Без `web.xml` или других конфигураций (только `pom.xml`).

Comment: Откуда им вызываться?

Comment: по конкретнее? т.е. мне самому его надо было вызвать? там же вроде аннотация для вызова стоит